# Simple jQuery assignment

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a on change method defined for my drop-down as follows -

```
$("[name=engine]").change( function() {
  var selectedIndex = $(this).val() ;
  var selectedValue = $("#engine option[value=333]").text()
  alert("Change..." + selectedIndex + " - "+ selectedValue);        
});
```

Here instead of `333`, i want to substitute the value of `selectedIndex`, how can I assign it to the `option[Value= ??]` element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way you create the `alert` text: String concatenation.

```
$("#engine option[value='" + selectedIndex + "']").text()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[name=engine]").change( function() {
    var selectedIndex = $(this).val() ;
    var selectedValue = $("#engine option[value="+selectedIndex +"]").text()
    alert("Change..." + selectedIndex + " - "+ selectedValue);

});
```

did you try this?